# angularjs textarea - how to keep it in sync with angularjs dropdowns selected values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a couple of drop downs  and based on selection I updated the textarea content, but when I am trying to update the text the function, I presume gets triggered, and does not let me update.

Here is my html :

```
 <textarea  ng-model="desc" ng-change="des"></textarea>
```

and angular

somehow the code got deleted.. please visit plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/pVSiNrnAOY0A5v0iTmYQ?p=preview

Comment: des() is a function not modal variable so you need to add bracket.

Comment: @Sam updated that and made it a function, it is still the same.

Comment: @TechnoCart that didn't work.

Comment: where is it going wrong? I suggest you inject $log into your service and add some log statements.

Comment: What you expect $scope.d to return? It has not been set, maybe you mean return $scope.d(), but this could cause an infinite loop, as the function updates $scope.desc which will trigger the ng-change...

Comment: A couple things, you shouldn't return anything in that function, that might be why it is not working at the moment. Also what is $scope.stat? You are assigning it to your ng-model for the textarea, so that could be causing issues as well.

Comment: @Sam $scope.d returns a string it has the same value as $scope.desc and $scope.dsc .. I was attempting different ways but couldn't figure... so it is a little redundant to use so many variables to just return same value.

Comment: @ribsies $scope.stat contains a list json objects, on match I assign its text to textarea.

Comment: ok, but then when the text area updates.. you call ng-change again and get an infinite loop

Comment: perhaps you could give a higher level description of what you are trying to do

Comment: @Sam see if the question is a little clearer now... I have 2 drop down to select from and that is why I have that function to filter is based on selection from those drop downs.

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper is that how you actually have your $scope.stat defined? With the parenthesis around it? That could be your problem. This question is difficult because there is so much missing code that could be causing the issue. I would recommend creating a plunker for your problem.

Comment: so you want whenever someone tries to change the textarea - for something else to try and look to see if the content should actually be something else to reflect something else on the scope? 
I think what you want to do is get rid of ng-change and use the $scope.$watch service to keep variables in sync as required.

Comment: @Sam done.. see plunker :)

Comment: Added a new plunker someone broke the first one. :(

Comment: I'm not sure Plunkr links can be broken - a snapshot is taken when you fork it which can't be changed. 
There are some console errors output from your solution and it could be clearer what it happening. I have posted an updated plunkr solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use watch functions, especially if values might change in the controller, as this ensures that they stay in sync. This solution also seems easier to see what is going on: 
[plunkr solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/x6PcfBFY2aiGe7GhUCCN?p=preview)

Just using a watch function to watch the selected values:

```
 $scope.$watch('selectedId', function(newValue){
    $scope.d();
  });
```

I am not sure if you want the user to be able to change the value in the textarea or not. If you don't, like in your example, then I suggest that you add the attribute ng-disabled="true" to your text area.

Answer (score 0):

you also need

```
$scope.des = function() {
    return $scope.d()
  }
```

Not sure what your trying todo, but if have just plunked this

```
// Code goes here
app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('main', function($scope) {
  $scope.desc = "";
  $scope.stat = "test";
  $scope.d = function() {
    for (var i = 0, len = $scope.stat.length; i < len; i++) {

      if ($scope.stat[i].Id == $scope.selectedId && $scope.statDate == $scope.stat[i].StatDate) {
        $scope.desc = $scope.stat[i].D;
        return $scope.stat[i].D;
      }
    }
    return "";
  };

  $scope.des = function() {
    return $scope.d()
  }
});
```

And I get your issue, if I comment out

```
// $scope.desc = $scope.stat[i].D;
```

it works, but I presume that bit you need :)

What are you trying todo? I think you are trying to change model as the view is changed. You might need a directive for this.

This is part of something I did for datetime stuff

```
.directive('formatteddate', function ($filter) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
```

This is the plunk of your code/html.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3GjP7YVsKFIYAAJQwmOK?p=preview

Comment: it does if you comment out 'that' line of code, if  you change the line of code. :)

Comment: this one // $scope.desc = $scope.stat[i].D; you can change this code to something that changes .desc and that works, but I don't  understand what you are doing with this.

Comment: The reason why it's not working in this plunk is because $scope.stat and $scope.statDate and all that nonsense are all undefined. So that if statement always 100% of the time evaluates to true, so that bit of code is always run which resets the $scope.desc to an undefined variable. So you try to type and it instantly gets reset. I assume he is trying to change the value to some specific value when you type in a certain value. He did not provide the code for this.

Comment: @Steve Drake, $scope.selectedId & $scope.statDate are two drop downs to select from of json arrays, of 1-20 and the other "03/20/2015" and :"03/26/2015"...... the stat array is  is like so: $scope.stat = ([{"Id":1,"D":"ABCD","StatDate":"03/20/2015"}, {"Id":2,"D":"ABCD" ,"StatDate":"03/26/2015"}]);

Comment: so, when you EDIT the textbox you want it to set to ABCD if Id=1 and the StartDate is correct? I have added

// Fake dropdown
$scope.selectedId =1;
$scope.statDate = '03/20/2015'

Comment: try the plunk again, enter one key and it LOCKS on ABCD , still feel that I don't really understand what you are trying todo.

Comment: @ ribsies is 100% correct, but once its valid it will lock the value on .D whatever D is

Comment: @Steve Drake see plunker.

Comment: @ribsies created plunker :)

Comment: someone broke that plunker, added a new one and froze it.

Comment: so, the code will just keep setting $scope.desc to the value from the array IF it finds it, is that what you want?? eg it will LOCK IT. The comment RE watch is correct it a better pattern.

Answer (score 0):

okay,so what about if you just update the **ng-model**  value of textarea to the value of your select dropdown.

Here's the plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/mXQTcBu5rOJaQJKEFKpm?p=preview

change the model name to some:

```
 <textarea ng-model="textarea" ng-change="desc()"></textarea>
```

and then update in, in your script where your code logic is:

```
$scope.d = function() {
    for (var i = 0, len = $scope.stat.length; i < len; i++) {
      console.log(i);
      if ($scope.stat[i].Id == $scope.selectedId && $scope.statDate == $scope.stat[i].StatDate) {
        $scope.desc = $scope.stat[i].D;
        **$scope.textarea=$scope.desc;**
        return $scope.stat[i].D;
      }
    }
    return "";
  };
```

Comment: Its working right,it is letting you modify the text area filed which wasn't happening before.